Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[Int]'
I'm trying to write a function to read a matrix from the console and then rotate it, but I encounter an error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[Int]'
I tried to replace it with .map , .flatMap but but everything stays the same

func readMatrix() {
        print("Enter matrix dimensions (n m):")
        guard let sizeInput = readLine(),
              let sizes = sizeInput.split(separator: " ").compactMap({ Int($0) }), // error 
              sizes.count == 2,
              let n = sizes.first,
              let m = sizes.last,
              n > 0, m > 0 else {
            print("Incorrect input of matrix dimensions")
            return
        }


guard let sizes = readLine()?.sizeInput.split(separator: " ").compactMap({ Int($0) }) instead?

just add case in front case let sizes =

As the error is telling you, nothing on the line in question returns an Optional, so it can't be part of the guard let statement.
Since readLine() does return an Optional, if you combine your first and second statements, then you have an Optional that works in a guard let statement:
func readMatrix() {
    print("Enter matrix dimensions (n m):")
    guard let sizes = readLine()?.split(separator: " ").compactMap({ Int($0) }), // <-- Here
          sizes.count == 2,
          let n = sizes.first,
          let m = sizes.last,
          n > 0, m > 0 else {
        print("Incorrect input of matrix dimensions")
        return
    }
}

Another option would be splitting the checks into two separate guard statements, with let sizes on a line on its own between the two. That would allow you to have different responses to readLine returning nil vs the subsequent checks.

You can mark the answer as correct/accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer

The guard statement is a collection of conditions, so the let statements are interpreted as conditional bindings. However, the second let is not a conditional binding, it is a plain declaration.
You could try using if for the first case instead:
func readMatrix() {
    print("Enter matrix dimensions (n m):")
    if let sizeInput = readLine() {
        let sizes = sizeInput.split(separator: " ").compactMap({ Int($0) })
        guard
            sizes.count == 2,
            let n = sizes.first,
            let m = sizes.last,
            n > 0,
            m > 0
        else {
            print("Incorrect input of matrix dimensions")
            return
        }
    }
}

This approach lets you differentiate between the two types of possible error:

no input (EOF)
bad input

